# Random changes after pause in Beamer

Tags: beamer, random

Working in Beamer I want to make a random construction and then after \pause (or using \onslide<>{}) add more information to the slide. The problem is that after the new text is undercover the random construction runs again and so it changes, which I which it didn't.

Does some one knows how to add more information to the slide without compiling again the random?

Here is an example, the random vector changes after \pause.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{pgfmath}
\newcommand\randmin{}
\newcommand\randmax{}
\newcommand\setrand[2]%
  {\def\randmin{#1}%
   \def\randmax{#2}
   }
\newcommand\nextrand
  {\pgfmathparse{int(int((rnd*(\randmax-\randmin+1)+\randmin)))}%
   \xdef\thisrand{\pgfmathresult}%
  }


\begin{document}


\begin{frame}
\setrand{0}{1}
$(\nextrand\thisrand,\nextrand\thisrand,\nextrand\thisrand,\nextrand\thisrand)$
\pause 

Text
 \end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please don't post code fragments. Instead, put your fragments into a complete compilable  document that shows the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `\newsavebox`,`\savebox`,`\usebox` sequence with the `\savebox` content created outside the `frame`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{pgfmath}
\newcommand\randmin{}
\newcommand\randmax{}
\newcommand\setrand[2]%
  {\def\randmin{#1}%
   \def\randmax{#2}
   }
\newcommand\nextrand
  {\pgfmathparse{int(int((rnd*(\randmax-\randmin+1)+\randmin)))}%
   \xdef\thisrand{\pgfmathresult}%
  }
  \newsavebox{\myrandlist}

\begin{document}


\setrand{0}{1}
\savebox{\myrandlist}{$(\nextrand\thisrand,\nextrand\thisrand,\nextrand\thisrand,\nextrand\thisrand)$}

\begin{frame}
\usebox{\myrandlist}
\pause 

Text
 \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]